# Using arrays to produce an output from a form. How do i change the order of this output?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below produces an output of

Apple,Orange
Sliced,Diced
Option1  Option2  Option3  Option4  ,Option1  Option2  Option3  Option4

I would like the output to be

Apple 
Sliced 
Option1  Option2  Option3  Option4

Orange 
Diced 
Option1  Option2  Option3  Option4

addOptions() creates the arrays from a form and showOptions() replaces elements with the array.

What needs to be changed in order to achieve this type of output? Please see this snippet

```js
var fruit
var prep
var saladsArr = [];
var salad = {
    "theFruit": []
    , "thePrep": []
    , "theOpt": []
};


function clickFruit() {
    fruit = document.getElementById('theTable').theFruitRad.value;
    console.log(fruit);
}

function clickPrep() {
    prep = document.getElementById('theTable').thePrepRad.value;
    console.log(prep);
}
// Create Arrays
function addOrder() {
    addOptions(document.getElementById('theTable'));
}

function addOptions(frm) {
    var buffTop = "";
    for (var i in frm.theFruitRad) {
        if (frm.theFruitRad[i].checked) salad.theFruit.push(frm.theFruitRad[i].value);
    }
    for (var i in frm.thePrepRad) {
        if (frm.thePrepRad[i].checked) salad.thePrep.push(frm.thePrepRad[i].value);
    }
    for (var i in frm.chkbox) {
        if (frm.chkbox[i].checked) {
            buffTop += frm.chkbox[i].value + " &nbsp;"
        }
    }
    salad.theOpt.push(buffTop);
    console.log(saladsArr.length);
    saladsArr.push(salad);
    resetForms();
}

function showOptions(frm) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < saladsArr.length; i++) {
        var salad = saladsArr[i];
        var html_salad = "<div class='resFruit" + [i] + "'>" + salad.theFruit + "</div>";
        html_salad += "<div class='resPrep" + [i] + "'>" + salad.thePrep + "</div>";
        html_salad += "<div class='resOpt" + [i] + "'>" + salad.theOpt + "</div><br>";
        
    }
    document.getElementById('finResults').innerHTML = html_salad;
    
}

function test() {
    console.log(salad);
    console.log(salad.theFruit);
    console.log(salad.thePrep);
    console.log(salad.theOpt);
}

function resetForms() {
    document.getElementById("theTable").reset();
}
```

```css
        div{
        background:white;
    }
    .resFruit {
        height: auto;
        background: yellow;
        color: black;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .resPrep {
        height: auto;
        background: green;
        color: black;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .resOpt {
        height: auto;
        background: orange;
        color: black;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    table {
        color: white;
    }
    
    #left {
        background: red;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        color: white;
    }
    
    #right {
        background: blue;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        color: white;
    }

#inputButton {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="temp.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="temp1.js"></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

    <div id="left">
        <form id="theTable"> <b><u>Fruit</u></b>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input required required type="radio" name="theFruit" id="theFruitRad" onclick="clickFruit()" value="Apple" /><i></i> Apple</label>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input required type="radio" name="theFruit" id="theFruitRad" onclick="clickFruit()" value="Orange" /> <i></i> Orange</label>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input required type="radio" name="theFruit" id="theFruitRad" onclick="clickFruit()" value="Banana" /> <i></i> Banana</label>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input required type="radio" name="theFruit" id="theFruitRad" onclick="clickFruit()" value="Pear" /> <i></i> Pear</label>
            <br>  <b><u><br>Prep</u></b>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input type="radio" name="prep" id="thePrepRad" onclick="clickPrep()" value="Sliced" /> <i></i> Sliced</label>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input type="radio" name="prep" id="thePrepRad" onclick="clickPrep()" value="Diced" /> <i></i> Diced</label>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input type="radio" name="prep" id="thePrepRad" onclick="clickPrep()" value="Peeled" /> <i></i> Peeled</label>
            <br>
            <label class="rad">
                <input type="radio" name="prep" id="thePrepRad" onclick="clickPrep()" value="Whole" /> <i></i> Whole</label>
            <br> <b><u>Options</u></b><br>
        
            <label class="ckb">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" id="chkbox" value="Option1" /> <i></i> Option1</label>
            <br>
            <label class="ckb">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" id="chkbox" value="Option2" /> <i></i> Option2</label>
            <br>
            <label class="ckb">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" id="chkbox" value="Option3" /> <i></i> Option3</label>
            <Br>
            <label class="ckb">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" id="chkbox" value="Option4" /> <i></i> Option4</label>
            </Br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="finResults"></div>
        <center>
            <input id="inputButton" type="button" value="Add" onClick="addOrder()" />
            <input id="inputButton" type="button" value="test" onClick="test()" />
            <input id="inputButton" type="button" value="Show Results" onClick="showOptions(document.getElementById('theTable'))" /> </center>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does frm look like, can you post the model ?

Comment: Include the HTML please

Comment: I updated the code to show that its been resolved.. thanks!

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Please never fix the problem in your question, because then the Q&A stops making sense. Also, please don't add any solution to your question. Solutions go into the answers sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the desired output, you just need to add a `for` loop to your `test` function as follows:

```
function test() {
    console.log(salad);
    for(var i = 0; i < salad.theFruit.length; i++) {
      console.log(salad.theFruit[i] || '');
      console.log(salad.thePrep[i] || '');
      console.log(salad.theOpt[i] || '');
      console.log('');
    }
}
```

Hope that's what you want.

When you print an array, it prints all the elements at once, separated by a comma. That was the case in your code which printed all the fruits at once, followed by preps and opts.

Adding a loop, we print the element at a particular index from all the 3 arrays at once. Thus, the element in the fruits array at the first position is printed, followed by the first element in the preps array, and the opts array. Then the elements at second position from all the 3 arrays and so on.